Yukawa theory scattering
I was trying to clarify the logics of QFT by reading David Tong's notes, Zee's Nutshell and other materials. In my understanding, the canonical quantization works as follows.

Given a Lagrangian, compute the Hamiltonian and separate it into the free term and the interaction term. (<- This is always in Schrodinger picture?)
Turn the interaction term into the interaction picture
Calculate $S$-matrix by approximating the time ordered exponential.

I'm using Yukawa Lagrangian (it might be a simplified version but I found it in Tong's note) as an example and in Step 1, I get
$$
\mathcal{L} = 
\partial_{\mu} \psi^{\ast} \partial^{\mu} \psi 
+ \frac{1}{2} \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial^{\mu} \phi 
- M^2 \psi^{\ast} \psi 
- \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2 
- g \psi^{\ast} \psi \phi \\
\mathcal{H} = 
\delta^{\mu\nu} \partial_{\mu} \psi^{\ast} \partial_{\nu} \psi 
+ \frac{1}{2} \delta^{\mu\nu} \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial_{\nu} \phi 
+ M^2 \psi^{\ast} \psi 
+ \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2 
+ g \psi^{\ast} \psi \phi \\
H_{\text{free}} = \int d^3 x \left(
\delta^{\mu\nu} \partial_{\mu} \psi^{\ast} \partial_{\nu} \psi 
+ \frac{1}{2} \delta^{\mu\nu} \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial_{\nu} \phi 
+ M^2 \psi^{\ast} \psi 
+ \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2 
\right) \\
H_{\text{int}} = \int d^3 x 
g \psi^{\ast} \psi \phi 
$$
I'm thinking I plug
$
e^{i H_{\text{free}} t} H_{\text{int}} e^{-i H_{\text{free}} t} 
$
into
$U(t_1, t_2) = T\exp \left(\int_{t_2}^{t_1} dt H_{?} \right)$
instead of
$
H_{\text{int}}
$,
based on how it was derived.
I'm confused of two points: First, in Tong's note, from around p.53, it looks $H_{\text{int}}$ is directly used.
Second point is, he plugs in
$$
\psi = \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2 \pi)^3 \sqrt{2 E_p}} \left(a_p e^{-ipx} + b_p^{\dagger} e^{+ipx} \right)
$$
into $H_{\text{int}}$,
where $px$ is an inner product of four momentum.
But isn't this a free field operator in Heisenberg picture, which doesn't solve the Euler Lagrange equation for this Yukawa Lagrangian?
I remember seeing on some material something like "because $\partial_t O_I = -i [O_I, H_0]$ looks exactly like the time development in the free theory, the same expressions can be used", but how is this field operator $\psi$ consistent with the Lagrangian?
Any help is appreciated.
